# jquery after last not displaying

Tags: jquery

I am creating an jquery ajax application.. where i got stuck

And i uploaded the images for better understanding.

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

and below is the code what i used for retriving the fetch data

```
$.post("ajx_dynamic.php", {st: start1, ed: end1}, function(return_data2){
    $(".main_div_class .single_div_class").last().after(html(return_data2));
});
```

Is the statement correct

```
$(".main_div_class .single_div_class").last().after(html(return_data2));
```

cos its not showing up the results after the last div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be

```
$(".jobs_container_class .single_job_class").last().after(return_data2);
```

**OR**

```
$(return_data2).insertAfter(".jobs_container_class .single_job_class:last")
```

Comment: let me know why use `($(return_data2)); `

Comment: Calling `$()` is not necessary if `return_data2` is a string containing markup. You only have to issue `after(return_data2)`.